# How to delete row from gridview's RowDataBound event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to delete a row from a gridview (based on a condition) and then add than row to another gridview inside of the "master" gridview's RowDataBound event. Originally I did not know that in order to call .DeleteRow(i) you needed to have an "ondelete" event handler. However, since all the gridview's .DeleteRow method does is call this event handler, I am confused as to how to use it. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

```
Protected Sub grdProduct_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdProduct.RowDataBound

    ' Grey out expired products
    Dim row As GridViewRow
    row = e.Row

    Dim incomingDate As String
    Dim incomingStatus As String = ""

    incomingDate = row.Cells(3).Text.ToString()
    incomingStatus = row.Cells(5).Text.ToString()

    If (e.Row.RowType <> DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Try
        Dim expDate As Date = incomingDate
        If (expDate < DateTime.Today Or incomingStatus.Equals("D")) Then

            'Create object for RowValues
            Dim RowValues As Object() = {"", "", "", "", "", ""}

            'Create counter to prevent out of bounds exception
            Dim i As Integer = row.Cells.Count

            'Fill row values appropriately
            For index As Integer = 0 To i - 1
                RowValues(index) = row.Cells(index).Text
            Next

            'create new data row
            dProdRow = dProdtable.Rows.Add(RowValues)
            dProdtable.AcceptChanges()

            grdProduct.DeleteRow(e.Row.RowIndex)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub grdProduct_Delete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles grdProduct.RowDeleting
    'Not sure what to do here
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of the `DeleteRow` method you could also simply delete the row from the datasource of the main grid and add it to the source of the nested grid  in any event of your choice(e.g. CommandEvent or Button-Click). You just have to call `MainGrid.DataBind()` afterwards.

Comment: I have the datasource declared in a public sub separate from the RowDataBound event. Would I have to change the scope of the datasource in order to do this? Unfortunately I need to use the RowDataBound event to test for the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to manipulate this at the datasource level rather than manipulating the UI components themselves.

For example:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    DataTable one  = ...
    DataTable two = ...

    var removeRows = (from c in one.AsEnumerable()
                     where c.Field<DateTime>("incomingDate")< incomingDate || 
                           c.Field<string>("incomingStatus")=="D"
                     select c).ToList();

   for(var item in removeRows)
   {
       two.ImportRow(item);
   }
   //now delete from initial table
   foreach(var item in removeRows)
   {
       one.Rows.Remove(item);
   } 

   //Now bind both grids
   grid1.DataSource=one;
   grid1.DataBind();
   grid2.DataSource=two;
   grid2.DataBind();

}
```

**Update - Sample toy program in VB.NET** Hopefully you can adapt it to your situation.

```
Sub Main
    Dim one As New DataTable()
    one.Columns.Add("one", GetType(Integer))
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        Dim r As DataRow = one.NewRow()
        r.ItemArray = New Object() {i}
        one.Rows.Add(r)
    Next

    Dim two As New DataTable()
    two.Columns.Add("one", GetType(Integer))
    For i As Integer = 0 To 9
        Dim r As DataRow = two.NewRow()
        r.ItemArray = New Object() {i}
        two.Rows.Add(r)
    Next
    Dim removeRows = (From c In one.AsEnumerable() Where c.Field(Of Integer)("one") = 5).ToList()

    For Each item As DataRow In removeRows
        two.ImportRow(item)
    Next

    For Each item As DataRow In removeRows
        one.Rows.Remove(item)
    Next

End Sub
```

I just realized that you are using VB.NET. You should be able to translate the above from C# to VB.NET. The general idea is there, anyway.

Comment: Does the ImportRow method remove the row from the original DataTable? From what I see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow(v=vs.80).aspx it just makes a copy.

Comment: @NealR It does not. You need to do that yourself. I updated my answer with the full working code.

Comment: I am having an impossible time converting the From... Where code into VB. Do you know if it is possible? I am getting errors oc C.Field and <DateTime> respectively. c.Field says "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Field' accepts this number of arguments." <DateTime> says "'DateTime' is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

Comment: VB does not like the .ToList() command: 'ToList' is not a member of 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of Systsem.Data.DataRow)